# Is there a good pattern for merging the results of two graphQL schemas?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I've been looking around to see if a pattern exists for merging two graphQL datasets which contain the same type of data. What I mean is, given the following two type definitions;

```
type StevesBooks {
  title: String
  author: String
}

type DavesBooks {
  title: String
  author: String
}
```

If both of those are implemented as graphQL schemas separately/remotely, each with their own set of resolvers, is there a pattern or paradigm I can draw from to create a third graphQL instance that combines these two, so I can query "SteveAndDavesBooks" at the same time?

I found `mergeSchemas` in the apolloServer API but that solves a different problem to this one and all of the conflict-resolution methods in there require you to "choose a side" so to speak, rather than combine the results.

Is there already-written plugin or library somewhere that will help to achieve the above or do you think this is going to be something bespoke that I need to do myself?

I saw that query federation is on the roadmap - does anyone know any more details about that because that sounds like what I'm after.